# Buttons with images in plain HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css

is there a way to add an image to a regular `<input type = "button" />` besides the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can have css for button .

```
 

background: url(images/blue.png)  ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes - you should be able to set the background image on the button in CSS. My preferred method is to use the button tag e.g.

```
<button type="submit">text</button>
```

You can put any html you want within the tag and style it.

Comment: <button type="submit"><img src="..." alt="" /><-Image</button>

Comment: Moak - true - but I would use CSS to add a background image somehow

Answer (score 1):

You want the "image" input type

```
<input type="image" src="/path/to/image.png" value="Click here" size="32,32" border="0" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Button in **HTML** (For location I'd normally place all images in a images folder)

```
<BUTTON type="submit" src="/images/Button.png" value="">
```

Button via **CSS**, where myBtn is defined in the class file

```
<BUTTON type="submit" class="myBtn" value="">
```

Where myBtn is defined in the class file

```
.myBtn{ 
background: url(/images/Button.PNG) no-repeat; 
cursor: pointer; 
width: 140px; 
height: 80px; 
border: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="button" style="background-image:url(flower.jpg)" value="Click">
```

It will set the background image for button using HTML.

Answer (score 0):

An image in the button or an image as the button?

Image AS button:

```
<input type="image" src="/images/myImage.png" alt="An image as a button"/>
```

Image inside button....I don't think so.